# Detect line of sight and distance between two object in TCP Server

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a 3D multiplayer game. I use Unity 3D as a platform to develop my Game Client. I have to build MySQL C# Console Application which serves me as a TCP server. I am connecting my client via TCP protocol to my Server application. I have the following scenario:

I have two players inside the game both wearing guns and trying to shoot each other.

Between them, there is a wall and Player 1 receives an error when trying to shoot Player 2: "Your target is not in the line of sight." (Normally because there is a wall between them)

However, Player 2 is using "hack" and he removes the wall so he does not receive this error and kills Player 1.

**My first question is:**
Obviously, it's not a good idea to count only on the client to decide if there is an object between two players to fine and error. What can I do in order my Server App to be able to detect that there is an object between the player and the target? What can you suggest?

**My second question is:**
How can I calculate the distance between two objects which are in my Server App? Is it possible and if so how?

Comment: C'mon, you mastered nuclear physics in one night, you'll be able to handle this! More seriously, the fact that most things happen client-side is exactly why most mmo's are facing hack issues. And most things happen client-side because it's so much cheaper... If you want to handle everything server-side, you need more servers and more power

Comment: I won't be using a "simple" console application as server. but will send positions and stuff from clients to server that "plays" the game internally so, even if players have removed the walls, the server doesn't care and calculate using its own mapping. But this idea might be stupid, idk

Comment: @Tony Stark I have implemented something similar just not as simple as "one console application" basically I have a dedicated server only for the world physics and checks. I used BulletSharp as physics engine and exported the basic terrain from unity and loaded it as *.obj in the engine, then everything is calculated and loaded server side, from path-finding to collisions double check and cheat checks on the players positions. Its a lot of work to add Geodata knowledge to the server but it sure is rewarding. Unfortunately the code is huge to share so I can point you to a guideline only...

Comment: What about if i run one version of the client in headless mode and make my dedicated server to check this trusted client? What worries me are the different scenes and how fast this client will respond.

Comment: Maybe it will work, depends on the server load, plus every time you have to double check something you will have to pass it through this client and then send the reply to the client if its low population it should be no problem but if u are looking at 1000 concurrent users it might get tricky. Also what kind of game are u making? there are different approaches for MMO or Shoot em up.

Comment: The game is MMORPG. My current plan is to load all scenes inside an headless client and my server will make requests to "ask" that client, client will respond back to my server and server will respond back to the player's client. What worries me i have described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52330693/unity3d-load-all-scenes-in-headless-mode-and-target-object-in-one-of-them

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that in your server you can access the data of all the users in your Game World. So what you could do it, every time a user claims a hit has been done, you double-check it in the server if that is actually possible.

To do so and find out the distance, you can user Raycasting:

```
Vector3 direction = (...);
RaycastHit hit;
Vector3 convertDirection = transform.TransformDirection(direction);

if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, convertDirection, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask))
{
    Debug.Log(hit.distance);
}
```

Edit: As Rafalon suggested, not sure how cost-efficient is to do this server-side. But you can do it. After all, **you are Ironman**

Comment: I can access the data of all the users and it is kept in the server. However I imagine i should generate something like a map data so the server can calculate if there is any line of sight.  On the second part of my question. I believe you did not get the point. The code you have shown is for Unity. My server app is simple C# console app.

Comment: If you cannot trust the client, you are going to check everything yourself from the server and for that you are going to need the ability to do operations on the world space. Maybe connecting your own "safe" client to the server.

Comment: The idea of connecting the own safe client to the server sounds like it may work. But how actually you imagine the connection to happen. Something like API ?

Comment: Users send/receive events to/from the server. Of course those are limited, because there are events thry should not be able to know about. Maybe you need a special kind of user, maybe introducing "roles", and run a client with the role "admin"