# Unity3D - Load all scenes in headless mode and target object in one of them

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 3D. I have build my own TCP Dedicated server as simple C# Console Application. In Unity I want to load all the scenes inside a headless client with their terrains and objects.

On request to that headless client via TCP I will point scene and two objects. The whole purpose of that is to respond me back if there is some other object between the given two. Something like "line of sight" feature.

What worries me is:

Can load all scenes and their object at start so on request i will not wait to load a scene ?

If i can load all scenes, how can i select one of them ?

All this i want to create as a feature giving trusted info to my dedicated server on player action collisions.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45742735/load-all-scenes-during-splash-screen/45743288#45743288). You can load them but activate them one by one when you need them

Comment: @Programmer thank you for your response. Do you think changing of scenes with happen quick enough in this way ? Do you think the approach i am taking is the best one to create trusted "line of sight" feature ?

Comment: @Programmer also am i going to be able to get the physics inside the game while the client is in headless mode? Let's say i have two players and wall between them. The headless client will be able to make raycast from player 1 to player 2 and "see" that there is a wall, right ?

Comment: I noticed you've been asking multiplayer networking security questions lately but the answer I linked has nothing to do with that. I only have one advice for you. If your players want to cheat, they will cheat regardless of how secure you think your code is. Just make users to sign in before playing then add feature that detect behaviors you consider as cheating then send to server and server should ban user if the condition is met. Yes, you can use physics code in a headless mode

Comment: Finally, you may not know this but writing your Unity code in C++ is much more secure than using C# which can be easily modified. If you really care about that, see [this](https://jacksondunstan.com/articles/3938) post. You can also only write the sensitive part in C++. It makes it harder but doesn't totally prevent the hacking.

Comment: @Programmer thank you for your advice and help. One last question. Once all the scenes are loaded `SetActiveScene` is going to switch them instantly with no extra loading delay what so ever ? Also what will happen if the server makes a request for one scene and second later makes request for another scene isn't that going to kinda "bug" it ?

Comment: The linked post I provided used `LoadSceneMode.Additive` so the activated scene will be added on top of the currently loaded scene. If you change it to  `LoadSceneMode.Single` it will close the current loaded scene and load the new one. There shouldn't be any delay with `LoadSceneMode.Additive`. Give it a try. Maybe [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/142482/what-is-the-different-between-loadscenemode-additive-and-loadscenemode-single) will help you explain what happens.